# How to save chronometer time like variables

Tags: android

I've been having some trouble in saving my Chronometer time across activities and restarts. When I try to use SharedPreferences, I get stuck because Chronometer is not a variable type like int and String.

To save variables I do it like this

```
SharedPreferences myVar = getSharedPreferences("VarName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myVar.edit();
    editor.putInt("var", integer);
    editor.commit();
```

and to retrieve

```
SharedPreferences myVar = this.getSharedPreferences("VarName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    integer= myVar.getInt("var",0);
    TextView.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
```

but when it comes to the Chronometer I don't know what to put in " editor.put***(); " and it usually ends up in a loop where my values that are being called are null, so it either crashes or nothing changes.

I've tried creating and onDestroy() method and with this `chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());` inside but it doesn't work. I've also tried `onRestoreInstanceState()` which also doesn't work.

This is my Simple Chronometer

```
  chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    chronometer.setFormat("Duration: %s");
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

    final ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggle_chronometer);

    /**
     * Toggles start and stop on the chronometer
     */
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (toggleButton.isChecked()){
                if(!running){
                    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
                    chronometer.start();
                    running = true;
                }
            }else{
                if(running){
                    chronometer.stop();
                    pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
                    showElapsedTime();
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

 /**
 * Resets the chronometer
 */
public void resetChronometer(View v){
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    showElapsedTime();
    pauseOffset = 0;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be wondering how I solved it.
I stored my `pauseOffSet`, `running` and `chronometer.getBase()` variables in Sharedpreferences specifically in the `onStop()` method and retrieved them in my `onStart()` method. Coding in Flow's website is what gave me the idea with his countdown timer.